# libgdx and TWL: Android app force closes on any TWL menu, works fine on Desktop

Tags: android, libgdx

I am implementing menus using TWL (http://twl.l33tlabs.org/) in an app written using Libgdx. The app runs fine if I don't start any menus, but as soon as I go to a menu screen it immediately force-closes. Menu screens work fine on the desktop version.

In which build path should TWL-android.jar be included (right now it behaves the same in main, android, and both)? And how will the program know to use the libraries from this .jar instead of the default gdx-twl.jar? Will I have to manually implement something in code to use one or the other depending on platform?

There does not seem to be any documentation or sample code of anyone using TWL on android, only mentioning that it can be done.

Running debugger attached to phone gives the following logcat error:

```
Could not find class 'com.badlogic.gdt.twl.Layout' referenced from method com.Nanners.OptionsScreen.<init>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Have a browse through [the Markdown Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - perhaps formatting your question would aid people in understanding the problem and responding with a solution. Large chunks of error code are difficult to read, if they are unformatted. :)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm planning to use TWL with libgdx, but i'd like to know if it'll work before investing time in it.

Comment: I never did, sadly. I've just ditched it and built my own menus. I liked it a lot and it was really easy to use, apart from not working on Android for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that TWL-android.jar should be added to android project's build path too. Location of .jar is not relevant.

Comment: Tried this, still crashes upon switching to any menu screen. Give this error in logcat:


    03-04 10:39:58.632: E/dalvikvm(28885): Could not find class 'com.badlogic.gdx.twl.Layout', referenced from method com.Nanners.OptionsScreen.<init>

Comment: you should also include gdx-twl on build path in your android project.

Comment: Adding gdw-twl to the android project prevents it from running, giving the error   
  `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1`

Answer (score 0):

When you add TWL-android.jar. As that is Android specific you can't use it on the core project, so the classes you are importing are the ones from gdx-twl. To make it simpler to explain I will divide it in different escenarios.

1. You add TWL-android to your Android buildpath. But you use Gdx-twl in your core project. Which isn't added. Thus getting a:

   ```
   Could not find class 'com.badlogic.gdx.twl.Layout'
   ```
2. You add both TWL-android AND Gdx-twl to your build path. Thus getting duplicated classes and:

   ```
   Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
   ```

**Solution**

If you use TWL-android classes, you can only do it inside the Android project:

- Merge Core, Desktop and Android project. Or
- Use [Interfacing with Platform Specific](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code)

If you use Gdx-twl:

- Don't do it.

Actually the best solution is to get rid of all twl stuff and use [Scene2d.Ui](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui) instead. Its crossplatform and much easier to use.